# Resize Image to fit Parent layout height and width

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, scaletype

I want to fit an `Imageview` according to `Height` and `width` of my `RelativeLayout` without disturbing its ratio. I am using a `LinearLayout` with a `weightSum` and adding two other layouts ie `RelativeLayout` with `weight` 20 and `LinearLayout` with `weight` 80. I am adding the `imageview` to the `RelativeLayout` to take up `weight` 20 but currently, my image takes up the width to its content and does not follow the width of the parent, thus resulting in pushing the other layout.

My Layout is as below:

layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/order_detail_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="1dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="20">
            <Droid.CenterFitImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:id="@+id/imgArticleThumb"
                android:src="@drawable/Icon" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="80"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <Droid.CustomTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/txtCategory"
                card_view:customFont="Fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf"
                android:textColor="@color/CatTitle"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:text="Category" />
            <Droid.CustomTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
                   android:ellipsize="end"
                android:singleLine="true"
                card_view:customFont="Fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:text="Title" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

CenterFitImageView.cs

```
protected override void OnMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
{    
    try
    {    
        if (Drawable != null)
        {
            int w = MeasureSpec.GetSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            int h = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)w * (float)Drawable.IntrinsicHeight / (float)Drawable.IntrinsicWidth);

            SetMeasuredDimension(w, h);
        }
        else
            base.OnMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        base.OnMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }    
}
```

Expected output:

[image]

My output:

[image]

Comment: Do you want to set 50%,50% of both view.?

Comment: How about you replace  `android:layout_weight="80"`and  `android:layout_weight="20"` by 50,50 respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***layout_width="wrap_content"*** on your root LinaerLayout, is where you have gone wrong. You have to use ***match_parent*** if you need your views to be aligned properly according to their weights.

**Just remember that if you are using layout_weights and weightSum, then you have to give the root layout and specific width or height depending upon the arrangement**. *wrap_content*, means display your layout, according to whatever size the child is.

So the resulting code will be

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    ....
    ....
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the output that I got
[image: layout_weight aligning views]

The first RelativeLayout with the ImageView is taking 20, and the other one with a TextView is taking 80.

Answer (score 0):

Just used android:layout_height="wrap_content" instead of match_parent for ImageView and also set your textview height and width wrap_content.

Answer (score 0):

First of all why you didn't use Linearlayout instead of RelativeLayout. When you are using all LinearLayout.

I will do this in this way.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/order_detail_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="1dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="40"
            android:gravity="center">
            <Droid.CenterFitImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:id="@+id/imgArticleThumb"
                android:src="@drawable/Icon" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="60"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">
            <Droid.CustomTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/txtCategory"
                card_view:customFont="Fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf"
                android:textColor="@color/CatTitle"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:text="Category" />
            <Droid.CustomTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:singleLine="true"
                card_view:customFont="Fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:text="Title" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: I want to add more components there. Does using Relative instead of Linear make a difference in this scenario?

Comment: you want to add more component in which layout ? I use LinearLayout or Relativelayout according to my need. Where its easy to use LinearLayout why should i go for Relative

Answer (score -1):

replace the `layout_width="0"` of the image with maxwidth.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would specify exactly which one to replace (as there are two with "0dp"), and the reason to why this would solve the issue.